# Anyone know any formatter for Reactjs for Vs Code?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am new to React and already loving it however I have a little problem. It takes too much time to format both JS and JSX.

Prettier and Beautify doesn't work. Is there anyone who could show me to the general direction for Reactjs code formatter for VS Code?

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for a solution for 2 days and I just found a solution and am gonna share in case someone else need it.

- Go to your .js react javascript file
- From the right bottom language mode menu select "JavaScript React"
- Use the key shortcut "Alt + Shift + F"

Your code will be formatted!

Answer (score -1):

Well for formatting Prettier and Beautify are the very best I have used for VSCode. But here are a few things that I hope helps you.

// ES7 React JS Snippets
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets

//BabelJS 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mgmcdermott.vscode-language-babel

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment! I use Prettier and Beautify  too but they don't work as they recognize both Js and HTML code.  Are ES7 React JS Snippets or Babel Js  able to format the code?